# QSqlTableModel Enter Edit Mode After InsertRecord

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Understanding that this question was answered previously, the model used was a QStandardItemModel.  Applying that solution using a QSqlTableModel did not achieve the same results.  So the question is:  How do I put the QTableView into edit mode after I insert a record?  The code below almost gets me there but it will edit the first field but a subsequent tab places it in the next field but for a record that was previously selected so I assume i am missing a step:

```
class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(336, 462)
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_db()
        self.setup_model()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        if self.db.isOpen():
            self.load_data()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.btn_New = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_New.setMinimumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setMaximumSize(QSize(70, 21))
        self.btn_New.setText('New')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_New)

    def setup_db(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase("QMYSQL")
        self.db.setHostName(myhost)
        self.db.setUserName(myuser)
        self.db.setPassword(mypassword)
        self.db.setDatabaseName(mydb)
        self.db.open()

    def setup_model(self):
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self,self.db)
        self.model.setTable("scldata")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, 'ID')
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, 'Foreign ID')
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts Start')
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts End')
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, 'Billing Rate')

    def load_data(self):
        rec = QSqlRecord()
        rec.append(QSqlField("recordid",QVariant.String))
        rec.append(QSqlField("svcdataid",QVariant.String))
        rec.setValue('recordid',str(uuid.uuid4()))
        rec.setValue('svcdataid', "ParentID")
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRecord(row,rec)
        ndx = self.model.index(row, 2)
        self.view.edit(ndx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the same `QSqlRecord` that the model provides besides to establish a new `currentIndex` in the `selectionModel`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql
import uuid

myhost = ""
myuser = ""
mypassword = ""
mydb = ""

class SclDataBrowse(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(336, 462)
        self.setup_ui()
        self.setup_db()
        self.setup_model()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        if self.db.isOpen():
            self.load_data()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.btn_New = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New')
        self.btn_New.setFixedSize(70, 21)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_New)

    def setup_db(self):
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase("QMYSQL")
        self.db.setHostName(myhost)
        self.db.setUserName(myuser)
        self.db.setPassword(mypassword)
        self.db.setDatabaseName(mydb)
        self.db.open()

    def setup_model(self):
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self,self.db)
        self.model.setTable("scldata")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        titles = ('ID', 'Foreign ID', 'Receipts Start', 'Receipts End', 'Billing Rate')
        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            self.model.setHeaderData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, title)

    def load_data(self):
        self.model.select()
        rec = self.model.record()
        rec.setValue('recordid',str(uuid.uuid4()))
        rec.setValue('svcdataid', "ParentID")
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRecord(row, rec)
        ndx = self.model.index(row, 2)
        self.view.edit(ndx)
        self.view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(ndx, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    combo = SclDataBrowse()
    combo.showMaximized()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This change had no bearing on the behavior; however I did add a `self.view.selectRow(row)` right before I call the edit and it worked.  The only problem I am getting from this approach is an error I am receiving `edit: editing failed`

Comment: @Elcid_91 I just found the error, try again, if you fail you could tell me the version of PyQt5 that you use.

Comment: @Elcid_91 some feedback?

Comment: eyllansec...the suggestion you gave definitely works but before I gave feedback on this, I needed to know why the submitAll() does not update the database.  I was just researching this when I got your comment.

Comment: @Elcid_91 It would be good to ask another question detailing your code since that depends on many factors, on the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: @Elcid_91 Maybe I expressed myself badly, what I say is that you do not edit the code you show in your question with the same code of my solution, a future reader will see that your code is the same as mine, and ask yourself where was the problem? :-)

Comment: No I got you.  My apologies - I was trying to copy my code and I must have pasted in my question instead.  Totally my fault.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eyllanesc!